# Calling a function template from another function template

Tags: c++

I have a function template that looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> GetComponent()
{
    for (auto const& c : Components)
    {
        if (std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(c))
        {
            return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(c);
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
}
```

And I'm trying to call it from another function template:

```
std::shared_ptr<GameObject> Object;

template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> GetComponent()
{
    return Object->GetComponent<T>();
}
```

But I get

```
syntax error: unexpected token ')', expected 'expression'
```

Comment: Any suggestions here will be just educated guesses. An answer with any chance of being right requires the question to include a [mcve], instead of small code snippets. The devil is in the details.

Comment: This gives me 'GetComponent': is not a member of 'GameObject'

Comment: Possible related reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: @songyuanyao: `Object` isn’t dependent here; it’s a global.

Comment: …Unless all that is embedded in a class template (so yes, MCVE).